# Use typed text from AutoComplete in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, even if that value is not in the Combo Box DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, sometimes the `ComboBox` has a list of items, but sometimes the list is empty.
I have enabled the `AutoCompleteMode`, in order for user to type in what item he wants.

I want to have the possibility to use the typed text from the user as a valid item.
I mean, in case the list is empty, the user can type in a text into `ComboBox` and to use that one as input.
Also, when the list is not empty, the user can type in a text into `ComboBox` and even if that item name is not in the list, to use it as input.

At the moment, it works just when the user types in a value that is in the list, then that value can be used. If the user types in a value that is not in the list, the value is not used as desired one.

This is how I enabled the `AutoComplete`:

```
private void DataGridNewOrders_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
            if (comboBox != null)
            {
                comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
            }
        }
```

Is there any property that allows the typed text from `ComboBox` to be used even if that text is not in the list ?

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am confident there is no “built-in” mechanism in the out-of-the-box `DataGridView` to allow the user to “add” items to a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`. I am pretty sure "you" are going to have to add the mechanism to “add an item to a combo box cell”. Something like a `Button` that pops up a small window with a text box so the user can add a value. Then the code can add the new value to the combo box cell.

Comment: This is doable; however, a combo box “implies” a “fixed” and pre-set number of values. It is unclear from your question “what” and how may items each combo box contains. Do all the combo boxes contain the same items or are they all different? If users are constantly “adding” items to the combo boxes, then I would question using the combo box control for this. It may not be the right control. Can you elaborate on what is currently in the combo boxes and why some “items” may be missing, requiring this addition by the user? Just guessing, however this sounds like a master/detail type layout.